# What happened to the people trapped in the past?

Tags: the-tomorrow-war

Time travel in the *The Tomorrow War* has two premises:

1. > Time only flows in one direction. It's like a river. The Jumplink placed two rafts on that river thirty years apart. Now, we can jump back and forth between them, but both rafts will always keep moving forward.
2. > [Charlie] Have you noticed how all of us, or at least most of us, are like over forty?
   >
   > [Dan] Yeah. You're thinking that, in order for the time jump to occur we have to be dead in the time we're jumping to? I mean, I imagine it's to avoid some sort of paradox.
   >
   > [Charlie] Which would lead me to believe that's why the people training us are so young.
   >
   > [Both] They haven't been born yet!

So as the events of the film play out, Dan's mission is successful, however, the Jumplink is destroyed and time travelling is no longer possible. This would lead to people be both stuck in the future (or maybe not as the jump back was automatic) and stuck in the past (the person who informed Dan that the Jumplink was destroyed was from the future).

I do not see a problem with people being stuck in the future, they had died in the past and would die in the "old" future. However, I see a problem with the ones stuck in the past. They were not born yet but as the "new" future unfolds they may still be born thus creating two of the same people, a newborn and adult version.

Considering they were worried about a paradox of having two of the same people in the same timeline how do the people stuck in the past affect this? Would they not be born, would they have to be euthanized, something else?

Comment: Presumably with the original jump back in time the timeline has been so irreparably changed that its extremely unlikely any of the future people would ever be born in the current timeline

Comment: Well, that was going to be my weekend viewing.. I'll have to find something else now.

Comment: @DannyMcG - Then you probably shouldn't have clicked on the question, then should you?

Comment: You're telling me they somehow managed to drain the military forces of the entire planet and then conscript randoms without picking anyone's parents and causing paradoxes anyway? Were all the actual soldiers sent to the future over 40?

Comment: According to the interpretation [here](https://www.thisisbarry.com/film/the-tomorrow-war-explained-with-timeline-diagrams/) it's actually two separate timelines, the one he calls "timeline 1", where there's a war happening in 2051, is the future of a world where no one in the 2020's went to the future to fight in a war, so Dan's life played out "normally" and he died in 2030. In this theory, the Dan who does go to the future is from a different "timeline 2" so he can have a different fate, and the war can be averted in that timeline.